# How can I jump to a file in dired after M-x locate?

Tags: dired

If I M-x locate a file, then want to open it in dired, there's no function to jump directly to the file.

I can only hit V, which opens the directory, but it does not highlight the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file and run `dired-jump` (bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd>).

Comment: And `dired-jump` is bound to `C-x C-j`. And you can use the command without opening the file, by providing a prefix arg: `C-u C-x C-j`. That prompts you for the file name.

Comment: Hmm, this does not work here. I'm just being thrown in /. I'm testing this on two platforms. What happens when you do it? It open the dired buffer in the containing directory and highlights the file?

Comment: Oh, `dired-jump` is part of `dired-x`. You need to `require` it.